# Reference request: Modulus of continuity of the map from parameter space to the space of probability measures

Tags: mathematical-statistics, likelihood, measure-theory, functional-data-analysis

I am thinking of the following condition in my research:

Let $\Theta \subset \mathbb R$ be the parameter space and $\mathbb P_\theta$ be the probability measure on sample space $\mathbb X$ associated with parameter $\theta$ ($\mathbb X = \mathbb R$ is fine). Suppose there exist a continuous function $s: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $s(0)=0$ such that:
$$
 \lVert\mathbb P_\theta -  \mathbb P_{\theta'}\rVert_{\text{TV}} \leq s(\lvert \theta - \theta'|).
$$
Intuitively this requires the map from $\Theta$ to the probability measures on $\mathbb X$ being uniformly continuous.

I am wondering:

1. Is there a name for the condition I mentioned above?
2. Which models satisfy this condition? (I can think of location models, Poisson, etc)
3. Is there reference for this kind of continuity as a functional?

Thanks!